# Protecting a directory using .htaccess and .htpasswd

Tags: php, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I want to protect an admin folder in my PHP web site from other people.
I created two files `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`, but when I enter to the index page on this folder it doesn't show me that dialog where I have to enter the username and the password, here are the content of the files :

The .htpasswd file :

```
mateo21:$1$MEqT//cb$hAVid.qmmSGFW/wDlIfQ81
ptipilou:$1$/lgP8dYa$sQNXcCP47KhP1sneRIZoO0
djfox:$1$lT7nqnsg$cVtoPfe0IgrjES7Ushmoy.
vincent:$1$h4oVHp3O$X7Ejpn.uuOhJRkT3qnw3i0
```

The .htaccess file :

```
AuthName "Page d'administration protégée"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/var/www/sec/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

I'm running Linux ubuntu and apache.

Comment: uh, you probably don't want to post your password hashes

Comment: @JonLin the web site isn't online it's on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to deny everything first. Try:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all

AuthName "Page d'administration protégée"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/var/www/sec/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

Answer (score 0):

If what @Jon Lin said doesn't work, then make sure you have

```
AllowOverride AuthConfig
```

in your /etc/httpd/httpd.conf file

If you can't find your configuration file, then try searching for it in terminal...

```
locate "httpd.conf"
```

Or

```
find /etc/ -name "httpd.conf"
```

Comment: I can't find that file anywhere